Why was Adam considered unique as a talking creature when the snake could speak as well?
Onkelos renders Bereishis 2:7

וַיִּ֩יצֶר֩ י״י֨ אֱלֹהִ֜ים אֶת⁠־הָֽאָדָ֗ם עָפָר֙ מִן⁠־הָ֣אֲדָמָ֔ה וַיִּפַּ֥ח בְּאַפָּ֖יו נִשְׁמַ֣ת חַיִּ֑ים וַֽיְהִ֥י הָֽאָדָ֖ם לְנֶ֥פֶשׁ חַיָּֽה
Hashem, God, formed the man from the dust of the ground and blew in his nostrils a breath of life and the man became a living being.

as

וּבְרָא יְיָ אֱלֹהִים יָת אָדָם עַפְרָא מִן אַרְעָא וּנְפַח בְּאַפּוֹהִי נִשְׁמְתָא דְּחַיֵי וַהֲוָת בְּאָדָם לְרוּחַ מְמַלְּלָא.
Hashem Elohim then formed Adam, dust from the ground, and He blew into his nostrils the breath of life. And so Adam became a speaking spirit.

In light of the snake speaking as well (if understood literally*) what was unique about man that only he was classed as a 'speaking spirit'?
*Some commentators understand it literally (e.g., R. Avraham ibn Ezra).
Onkelos translates Bereishis 3:1 as

וְחִוְיָא הֲוָה חֲכִים מִכֹּל חַיַּת בָּרָא דַּעֲבַד יְיָ אֱלֹהִים וַאֲמַר לְאִתְּתָא בְּקוּשְׁטָא אֲמַר יְיָ לָא תֵּיכְלוּן מִכֹּל אִילָן גִּנְּתָא.
The serpent was more cunning than any beast of the field which Hashem Elohim made; it said to the woman, “Did Hashem truly say that you should not eat from all the trees of the Garden?”

which would seem to indicate that he agrees with that reading

Its big machlokes reishonim how Chava could understand the snake

@Shlomy do elaborate please for those of us not familiar

R Avraham ibn Ezra cites a bunch of them https://mg.alhatorah.org/Dual/Ibn_Ezra_First_Commentary/Bereshit/3.1#m4e0n6

The Ohr Chaim here says that it wasn't speech such as we have it, but rather a standard hiss of a snake that Chava could understand.

The original Parseltongue!

The original python script

+1 btw R Avraham ibn Ezra already mentions this solution in the name of others : אבן עזרא פירוש ראשון בראשית ג':א' והנחש – יש אומרים: כי האשה היתה מבינה ויודעת לשון חיות, ויפרשו: ויאמר הנחש ברמיזות. NOW THE SERPENT. Some say that the woman understood and knew the language of the animals. They interpret And the serpent said as meaning, that the serpent spoke through signs.

Perhaps you can answer according to the chizkuni that says the snake got wisdom because it ate from the aitz hadaas (since wasn't commanded in not eating from it). So naturally it didn't have the ability to speak like man did.

+1 but for the record Chizkuni doesn’t seem to suggest that the snake obtained the ability to speak from the Etz HaDaas; rather, he implies that it imparted the highest animal intelligence. Chizkuni writes that the ability to speak was granted by God, similar to the way He granted speech to the donkey (which could also provide a possible solution, even though the Torah is silent on explicitly granting speech here).

Based on Chesed LeAvraham 4:5, and my general understanding:
There are two levels to intellect - the first is Chochma, and the second is Binah. Chochma is much higher, and more subtle, than Binah.
The Human being is the only creature that was created from Chochma. Animals were created with Binah.
Understanding the difference between Chochma and Binah should help understand the difference between the speech of humans and the speech of animals.
The problem is, this is quite hard to explain (we are trying to talk about the things that we use to talk, so that's understandable). I will give two different angles and then summarise and hope that it's a good explanation.

I came to answer this question and I didn't know what the answer was. I looked here and there and thought a bit and at some point, I figured out the answer. That happened in a split second - I had the full answer. The only problem is, it's taking me time to type it all out and put it into words, but nonetheless, everything I am writing here was all there in the initial "aha" moment, even if I didn't know exactly what words and explanations I would use to answer the question at that time.

In this example, the "aha" event was a Chochma event. The idea in its pure, "conceptual" form entered my intellect. Then, the idea was passed into my Binah,  which took over in putting it into words. In this example, Chochma is almost magical - its the part of our brain whose currency is actual grasping of ideas, and is very lofty. Binah is more like a computer that processes ideas. It's still lofty, but is more akin to something we can mimick with computers, which brings us to the next example:

AI language models spend a lot of time reminding us that no, they are not actually a person, and don't actually know anything and it's all an illusion. They are not speaking to us in the way we speak, with actual awareness of what they are saying as they say it. They don't have ideas, or conceive of concepts. They are just very very good at manipulating letters and words using logical processes and computation, so that we find it useful.

ChatGPT could change its "I am not what you think I am" reminders to be "I don't have any Chochma, it's an illusion. I have something akin to binah, I process data, but I don't know what I am actually doing". The magical ingredient of knowing the meaning of the words and phrases I am using is a Chochma skill, and that's unique to humans. Animals have only a very very small, insignificant degree of Chochma, if at all.
Conclusion: So, to the commentaries that bring the point that the Nachash's speech was fundamentally different to humans, I think the difference lies here. The Nachash was more like an AI LLM in its speech than a human, if not exactly the same. It could express its desire, and even do so in a clever (or crafty) way, but it was still doing so out of instinct, rather than its own essence. Humans, on the other hand, are literally made out of the stuff of true, knowing speech - Chochma.

Oh no, Chava was taken in by an AI bot ! I can't say that I'm able to wrap my head around this kind of stuff but +1 for your thoughtful engagement

@Nahum Try, you are very smart, you can figure many things out if you put your mind to it, this is not that hard (but I am a bad explainer, so go elsewhere). Re AI: the other day I asked AI a question, and it gave the most convincing sounding answer. Then I asked another AI, and it gave the exact opposite argument, and it was just as convincing. Shows how easy it is to get taken in by AI! It's almost like a chameleon or one of the mimicking cephalopods, but specifically is really really good at mimicking "good answers that humans will think make perfect sense".
